# Clear/reset filter on buttons from active to non-active - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a filter on a bunch of buttons, they are initially active therefore I apply an active class via `[class.active]`.

I have introduced a "clear all" option to the label of the button to essentially remove all the active classes on all the buttons. The click handler has a `clearContactMethod()` handler that takes care of the actually data clear. So its just the removal of the css class of 'active'. I have added another click handler of `!entry.isContactMethodActive` to the label to try and set the active to false. But this does not do anything.

I like the approach of adding my active class without calling upon my .ts file so I am wondering if this can be taken care of component level.

```
<label for="contactMethod">Contact method <small (click)="clearContactMethods(); !entry.isContactMethodActive">(Clear all)</small></label>

<button [class.active]="!entry.isContactMethodActive"
      (click)="toggle(entry.contactMethod); entry.isContactMethodActive = !entry.isContactMethodActive" type="button" *ngFor="let entry of contactLog | contactMethodFilter">{{entry.contactMethod}}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd part of this click handler doesn't seem to do anything when it probably should be doing assignment:

```
(click)="clearContactMethods(); !entry.isContactMethodActive"
```

Maybe it should be?

```
(click)="clearContactMethods(); entry.isContactMethodActive = !entry.isContactMethodActive"
```

Comment: Yes I tried that previously, but not doing anything unfortunately

Comment: Did you add it on the label as well?